# Memory management in Rust

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

In the Rust book, under the section of [Memory and Allocation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-01-what-is-ownership.html#memory-and-allocation), it says:

> The GC keeps track of and cleans up memory that isn’t being used anymore, and we don’t need to think about it...
>
> Rust takes a different path: the memory is automatically returned once the variable that owns it goes out of scope.

So in Rust, memory automatically frees up (unlike c)… but isn't that what Garbage Collectors do.
Then how is Rust's memory management any different from the usual GC?

Comment: It's different because there's no GC. Whoever owns a piece of memory is responsible for freeing it. Generally this happens when the owner is dropped, which automatically happens when its enclosing scope ends. It's an idea called [Resource Acquisition Is Initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) which C++ popularized and Rust took and ran with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Garbage collectors solve a different problem.

They do not simply free an object when it goes out of scope. If you have stored a reference to the object somewhere, they keep the object alive even though it goes out of scope.

Rust forbids you (at compile-time) to have any references left, so it can safely free the object. Garbage collectors will eventually run [a complicated algorithm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_management#mark-and-sweep_algorithm) to check if an object has any active references left. (Detecting unused cycles, e.g. when two objects point at each other, but nothing else holds a reference to them.)

This may lead to what is called a "GC pause", interrupting the program for an undetermined time. On the other hand, it allows you, the programmer, to simply put references wherever you like (almost) without worry.

Answer (score 0):

Let's imagine you have code like this:

```
fn func() {
    let s = String::from("abc");
    let i = 2;
    let b = Box::new(2);
}
```

All of these 3 are located on stack. Even **"Box::new"** variable creates data on the heap, it stores reference to this data on the stack of current frame(function "func") in this case.
When the stack frame is going out of scope, the data will be dropped. If you pass string "s" to the function by value, it'll move responsibility to free memory to that scope. So it cost's nothing to handle this kinds of object.

Another case is "std::rc::Rc". It behaves like smart pointers in C++. In this case you'll have additionally a reference counter, that tracks how many instances of "std::rc::Rc" is alive at the moment. Important that all of these instances will point to same data. When the last instance of "RC" is dropped, the counter will be zero and the data it's pointed to releases.

So basically it's not actually a GC. It's a set of constraints to the compiler(for regular objects) + "std::rc::Rc" wrapper in case if multiple ownership is needed.